# What are the drawbacks of getting a free domain name

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system, postfix, domain, subdomain

To configure a server, especially its email services, I'd need several `@serverdomainname.topdomain`.

I saw it is possible to pick some free domain names that would end in `.tk`, `.ga`, `.xyz`, etc.

I don't care about being well referenced by search engines.

Knowing this, what are the drawbacks of using free registrars ?

The dual question would be : how these businesses survive?

Do not-self-signed SSL/TLS certificates cost more for "exotic" top domains than for "classical" ones (e.g `.com`) ?

What is the bad consequence of a free domain name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the bad consequence of a free domain name?

Some possible consequences:

- bad for SEO (but you said you don't care)
- many corporations **block** new or not-so-new extensions, or certain TLDs that have high rates of spam/malware, and the extensions you've mentioned do not have good reputation. When was the last time you visited a legitimate website on .tk ? And since you've mentioned **email** service, then it's quite possible you will have **delivery** problems, more than average.
- trust factor: it's hard to **trust** anybody using a free domain name especially in one of these contemplated extensions

Last but not least, read the **terms** carefully. Free does not mean no strings attached or no conditions.

It all depends on what you want to do. If E-mail is a central part of your project, then I would ditch the idea. Delivery is already difficult enough in normal conditions, you don't want to create more hurdles considering that domain names are overall very cheap.

In general free service can be terminated at short notice and without compensation. Many people are [complaining](https://www.trustpilot.com/review/freenom.com) about Freenom (the provider of .ga .ml etc) so do your research and buyer beware.

Answer (score 3):

> The dual question would be : how these businesses survive?

An excellent question. Do your own research on the organization's business model and finances. It costs money to provide (or resell) competent name registration and DNS services. Although, it might be cheap enough relative to the rest of their hosting services to bundle it for "free".

> Do not-self-signed SSL/TLS certificates cost more for "exotic" top
>   domains than for "classical" ones (e.g .com) ?

No. x509 certificate issuers tend to have similar prices for whatever TLD they support. Let's Encrypt takes it to extremes, signing anything on the public suffix list for free.

Domain registries set policy for getting a name, including fees. Some are more premium than others. Check the price of these giveaway TLDs on retail name registrars, they are not going to be too expensive.